# Calculating days difference on rolling basis depending on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a calculated column using dplyr to get the days difference between the reference date(current) and a future date on a rolling basis. For e.g, I have a data frame like-

```
sample = data.frame(dates = seq(today(), today() + weeks(3), by = 1), qty = 
         floor(100 * rnorm(22)))
```

What I want to achieve is create a new column, say days_to which will be 0 if the qty >=0. However if qty < 0, then days_to should be the number of days till the qty goes above 0. If the qty doesn't go above 0 for any future date, then days_to = NA/Inf (not important). So for the above example it should look something like -

```
dates       qty days_to
10/17/2018  175 0
10/18/2018  -69 2
10/19/2018  -20 1
10/20/2018  113 0
10/21/2018  7   0
10/22/2018  120 0
10/23/2018  48  0
10/24/2018  -31 NA
10/25/2018  -9  NA
10/26/2018  -87 NA
```

I need to do this for a large number of rows(~2M) on a grouped variable and hence trying to use dplyr to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
sampledplyr <- sample %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(qty > 0 & lag(qty) < 0)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(days_to = if_else(qty < 0, n() - row_number() + 1L, 0L)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
print(sampledplyr, n=22)
# # A tibble: 22 x 3
#    dates        qty days_to
#    <date>     <dbl>   <int>
#  1 2018-10-17   -63       1
#  2 2018-10-18    18       0
#  3 2018-10-19   -84       1
#  4 2018-10-20   159       0
#  5 2018-10-21    32       0
#  6 2018-10-22   -83       1
#  7 2018-10-23    48       0
#  8 2018-10-24    73       0
#  9 2018-10-25    57       0
# 10 2018-10-26   -31       1
# 11 2018-10-27   151       0
# 12 2018-10-28    38       0
# 13 2018-10-29   -63       2
# 14 2018-10-30  -222       1
# 15 2018-10-31   112       0
# 16 2018-11-01    -5       2
# 17 2018-11-02    -2       1
# 18 2018-11-03    94       0
# 19 2018-11-04    82       0
# 20 2018-11-05    59       0
# 21 2018-11-06    91       0
# 22 2018-11-07    78       0
```

## `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
sampledt <- as.data.table(sample)
sampledt[,days_to := ifelse(qty < 0, .N - seq_len(nrow(.SD)) + 1L, 0L),
         by = cumsum(qty > 0 & lag(qty) < 0)]
```

(Same output.)

---

Data:

```
set.seed(1) # alway
sample = data.frame(dates = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 3*7, by = 1),
                    qty = floor(100 * rnorm(22)))
```

Comment: This solution works for the sample I provided, but if the dates have irregular gaps in between then it fails.

Comment: The `dates` field is never used, why would they matter? Do you need to order the data first?

Comment: No but the days_to in case of irregular dates becomes the number of indices or rows ahead. You then need to get the Date on that index and subtract that. I think I didn't make that clear in the question, and you solution acts as a step towards that so it is fine. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay, I didn't get that from the question, I see your point now. You'll need to post *representative data* to get more help. Perhaps find a random seed that presents the problem as you see it. Provide that seed (and the code to generate, if different from above), and I'll take a look.